Hard drive parameter has exceeded its normal operating range
I few days ago, I started seeing this message during boot:
NOTICE - HD SELF MONITORING SYSTEM has reported that a parameter has exceeded its
normal operating range. HP recommends that you backup your data regularly. A
parameter out of range may or may not indicate a potential hard drive problem.
Press F1 to continue, F10 to enter SETUP
When I hit F1, it used to boot normally but then I noticed that my secondary hard drive is not visible in Windows Explorer. Now this message isn't appearing anymore when booting and BIOS cannot detect that hard drive either.
The hard drive never showed any signs of normal malfunction (sounds etc.) and never had any physical damage etc. It looks as new except some dust it accumulated over the years.
I switched SATA cables to see if they were corrupted but in vain. I put that hard drive in an enclosure but that didn't work either. The hard drive does spin when I turn on power on this enclosure. The computer boots fine without any issue but the secondary drive isn't visible at all.
Question: How can I retrieve data from the secondary drive which has these problems?
OS: Windows 8.1 Pro
Primary disk: 250GB SSD internal
Secondary disk: 2TB HDD internal

Since you've tried putting it in an external enclosure (presumably using another PC, as well), and it does not show in OS or BIOS, you've determined it's bad. If you have made disk images, use them, though you'll lose data since the image was made. Other than that, stop trying to use the HDD and check the cost of commercial data recovery... and their evaluation of likelihood of recovering any data. If it's worth the cost, they can replace defective heads, IC's or other parts to attempt reading data.

"The hard drive never showed any signs of normal malfunction" - You mean other than the HP firmware detecting a problem with the drive? Your drive definitely failed.
